# Passing all files in a folder via Terraform

Tags: terraform, monitoring, grafana

I'm building a monitoring stack for our internal projects. I would like for them to be able to design their own monitoring dashboards to be used inside Grafana so I cannot predict what those will be called.

I created a folder called `grafana_dashboard`, where I will be instructing them to store their dashboard as JSON files and I want to pass all the contents of that folder to the Grafana instance.

I have tried a number of variations of this :

```
resource "grafana_dashboard" "dashboards" {
  for_each = fileset(path.module, "grafana_dashboard/*.json")
  config_json = "${each.key}"
  depends_on = [aiven_service.grafana]
}
```

But keep getting this error:

```
Error: invalid character 'g' looking for beginning of value

  on ../modules/monitoring/grafana.tf line 139, in resource "grafana_dashboard" "dashboards":
 139: resource "grafana_dashboard" "dashboards" {
```

Can any of you see what I'm doing wrong?

Here's an example of one of the .json files i'm trying to pass:

```
{
  "annotations": {
    "list": [
      {
        "builtIn": 1,
        "datasource": "-- Grafana --",
        "enable": true,
        "hide": true,
        "iconColor": "rgba(0, 211, 255, 1)",
        "name": "Annotations & Alerts",
        "type": "dashboard"
      },
      {
        "datasource": "Prometheus",
        "enable": true,
        "expr": "sum(changes(nginx_ingress_controller_config_last_reload_successful_timestamp_seconds{instance!=\"unknown\",controller_class=~\"$controller_class\",namespace=~\"$namespace\"}[30s])) by (controller_class)",
        "hide": false,
        "iconColor": "rgba(255, 96, 96, 1)",
        "limit": 100,
        "name": "Config Reloads",
        "showIn": 0,
        "step": "30s",
        "tagKeys": "controller_class",
        "tags": [],
        "titleFormat": "Config Reloaded",
        "type": "tags"
      }
    ]
  },
  "description": "Ingress-nginx supports a rich collection of prometheus metrics. If you have prometheus and grafana installed on your cluster then prometheus will already be scraping this data due to the scrape annotation on the deployment.",
  "editable": false,
  "gnetId": 9614,
  "graphTooltip": 0,
  "id": 18,
  "iteration": 1574177838584,
  "links": [],
  "panels": [
    {
      "columns": [
        {
          "text": "Current",
          "value": "current"
        }
      ],
      "datasource": "Prometheus",
      "fontSize": "100%",
      "gridPos": {
        "h": 15,
        "w": 24,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0
      },
      "height": "1024",
      "id": 85,
      "links": [],
      "options": {},
      "pageSize": 15,
      "scroll": true,
      "showHeader": true,
      "sort": {
        "col": 1,
        "desc": false
      },
      "styles": [
        {
          "alias": "Time",
          "dateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
          "pattern": "Time",
          "type": "date"
        },
        {
          "alias": "TTL",
          "colorMode": "cell",
          "colors": [
            "rgba(245, 54, 54, 0.9)",
            "rgba(237, 129, 40, 0.89)",
            "rgba(50, 172, 45, 0.97)"
          ],
          "dateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
          "decimals": 0,
          "pattern": "Current",
          "thresholds": [
            "0",
            "691200"
          ],
          "type": "number",
          "unit": "s"
        },
        {
          "alias": "",
          "colorMode": null,
          "colors": [
            "rgba(245, 54, 54, 0.9)",
            "rgba(237, 129, 40, 0.89)",
            "rgba(50, 172, 45, 0.97)"
          ],
          "decimals": 2,
          "pattern": "/.*/",
          "thresholds": [],
          "type": "number",
          "unit": "short"
        }
      ],
      "targets": [
        {
          "expr": "avg(nginx_ingress_controller_ssl_expire_time_seconds{kubernetes_pod_name=~\"$controller\",namespace=~\"$namespace\",ingress=~\"$ingress\"}) by (host) - time()",
          "format": "time_series",
          "instant": false,
          "intervalFactor": 1,
          "legendFormat": "{{ host }}",
          "metric": "gke_letsencrypt_cert_expiration",
          "refId": "A",
          "step": 1
        }
      ],
      "title": "Ingress Certificate Expiry",
      "transform": "timeseries_aggregations",
      "type": "table"
    }
  ],
  "refresh": "5s",
  "schemaVersion": 19,
  "style": "dark",
  "tags": [
    "nginx"
  ],
  "templating": {
    "list": [
      {
        "allValue": ".*",
        "current": {
          "text": "All",
          "value": "$__all"
        },
        "datasource": "Prometheus",
        "definition": "",
        "hide": 0,
        "includeAll": true,
        "label": "Namespace",
        "multi": false,
        "name": "namespace",
        "options": [],
        "query": "label_values(nginx_ingress_controller_config_hash, controller_namespace)",
        "refresh": 1,
        "regex": "",
        "skipUrlSync": false,
        "sort": 0,
        "tagValuesQuery": "",
        "tags": [],
        "tagsQuery": "",
        "type": "query",
        "useTags": false
      },
      {
        "allValue": ".*",
        "current": {
          "text": "All",
          "value": "$__all"
        },
        "datasource": "Prometheus",
        "definition": "",
        "hide": 0,
        "includeAll": true,
        "label": "Controller Class",
        "multi": false,
        "name": "controller_class",
        "options": [],
        "query": "label_values(nginx_ingress_controller_config_hash{namespace=~\"$namespace\"}, controller_class) ",
        "refresh": 1,
        "regex": "",
        "skipUrlSync": false,
        "sort": 0,
        "tagValuesQuery": "",
        "tags": [],
        "tagsQuery": "",
        "type": "query",
        "useTags": false
      },
      {
        "allValue": ".*",
        "current": {
          "text": "All",
          "value": "$__all"
        },
        "datasource": "Prometheus",
        "definition": "",
        "hide": 0,
        "includeAll": true,
        "label": "Controller",
        "multi": false,
        "name": "controller",
        "options": [],
        "query": "label_values(nginx_ingress_controller_config_hash{namespace=~\"$namespace\",controller_class=~\"$controller_class\"}, controller_pod) ",
        "refresh": 1,
        "regex": "",
        "skipUrlSync": false,
        "sort": 0,
        "tagValuesQuery": "",
        "tags": [],
        "tagsQuery": "",
        "type": "query",
        "useTags": false
      },
      {
        "allValue": ".*",
        "current": {
          "text": "All",
          "value": "$__all"
        },
        "datasource": "Prometheus",
        "definition": "",
        "hide": 0,
        "includeAll": true,
        "label": "Ingress",
        "multi": false,
        "name": "ingress",
        "options": [],
        "query": "label_values(nginx_ingress_controller_requests{namespace=~\"$namespace\",controller_class=~\"$controller_class\",controller=~\"$controller\"}, ingress) ",
        "refresh": 1,
        "regex": "",
        "skipUrlSync": false,
        "sort": 2,
        "tagValuesQuery": "",
        "tags": [],
        "tagsQuery": "",
        "type": "query",
        "useTags": false
      }
    ]
  },
  "time": {
    "from": "now-5m",
    "to": "now"
  },
  "timepicker": {
    "refresh_intervals": [
      "5s",
      "10s",
      "30s",
      "2m",
      "5m",
      "15m",
      "30m",
      "1h",
      "2h",
      "1d"
    ],
    "time_options": [
      "5m",
      "15m",
      "1h",
      "6h",
      "12h",
      "24h",
      "2d",
      "7d",
      "30d"
    ]
  },
  "timezone": "browser",
  "title": "Cert-manager",
  "uid": "nginx",
  "version": 12
}
```

This works, so I know that I can do it, but doesn't suit my needs as I'd need to hardcode the name of each file:

```
resource "grafana_dashboard" "nginx_ingress_controller" {
  config_json = templatefile("${path.module}/grafana_dashboard/nginx-ingress-controller.json", { DS_PROMETHEUS = local.prometheus_datasource_name })
  depends_on = [aiven_service.grafana]
}
```

Comment: Hello, how are you? I think the problem is not in your script but a syntax error on json file.

Comment: Hey ! I'm good, thanks, you ? That's a direction i haven't yet explored. Would you like to see one of those files ?

Comment: I'm fine. Could be useful for ours if you share this files :)

Comment: Tanks ! I've amended my question to include one ^^

Comment: Do you tried to run command with only once file? Prefer this file shared with us...

Comment: I've added code that works in my question

Comment: The return of `fileset` is a list and not a map, so `each.key` is slightly awkward here and may be causing a problem.

Answer (score 6):

You need to actually use the file contents in your `config_json` parameter to the `grafana_dashboard`.

Switching your resource definition to the following should be enough:

```
resource "grafana_dashboard" "dashboards" {
  for_each    = fileset(path.module, "grafana_dashboard/*.json")
  config_json = file("${path.module}/${each.key}")
  depends_on  = [aiven_service.grafana]
}
```

Comment: Much better using your method, thank you. But the file(each.key) function fails

Comment: Fails how? Can you edit your question to show the error?

Comment: The paths returned from `fileset` are relative to the directory given in its first argument, so to get those back into absolute paths again would require something like `file("${path.module}/${each.key}")`, if module is in a directory other than the current working directory.